# Find and replace in python

Tags: python, replace

Good Morning,

I m a beginner in python and I would like to have a little help :

I ll give you an exemple :

I got in a file:

```
blabla add_signed_123_548 blabla
blabla add_unsigned_77_10 blabla
```

And i want :

```
blabla adder blabla
blabla adder blabla
```

I have to find them then I have to replace them by adder.
I got no information about the number i gave random one.
But I don't know how you pick the entire string ?

I want to find 'add_' then i want to replace adder_signed_123_548 is it doable?

I hope it was clear.
Thx for help :)

Comment: Hum, not clear for me at least :S

Comment: Are you searching for some kind of regular expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This replaces all words that start with `add_` with `adder`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """foo bar add_signed_123_548 foo bar
... Baddest add_unsigned_77_10 additional"""
>>> print(re.sub(r"\badd_\w+", "adder", s))
foo bar adder foo bar
Baddest adder additional
```

The `\b` word boundary anchor makes sure that `add_` is only matched at the start of a word.

Comment: in fact, there is a lot of random number after all add_signed and I can t check all my file,

Comment: @user1398179: Yes, the regular expression `\w+` matches any number of alphanumeric characters. Is the output the way you want it?

Answer (score 1):

An answer without regex:

```
>>> value = "blabla add_signed_123_548 blabla"
>>> print ' '.join((word, 'adder')[word.startswith('add_')] for word in value.split())
blabla adder blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take your input string and split it on the underscores like `'add_signed_123_548'.split('_')` which will give you a list of all your component pieces `['add', 'signed', '123', '548']`, and from there you can process it however you need to.